# php endforeach every string random color

Tags: php

I am trying to give every string a random color. But all the colors are the same and only change on page load.

Here is my code

```
<?php
$variable = 'value1, value2, value3, value4, value5';
$colors= array("pink", "light-blue", "indigo", "purple", "orange", "green");
$random_color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
$arrs = explode(',', $variable);

foreach($arrs as $arr): ?>
    <span style="color: <?php echo $random_color; ?>"><?php echo $arr ?></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: `$random_color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];` should be inside the `foreach` loop

Comment: You only select a colour once, outside your `foreach` loop, so the colours will be the same.

Comment: You randomize `$random_color` only once. Put it inside your `foreach`

Comment: Thank you, I forget to place this inside the foreach loop!

Answer (score 0):

Put `$random_color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];` inside for loop:

```
$variable = 'value1, value2, value3, value4, value5';
$colors= array("pink", "light-blue", "indigo", "purple", "orange", "green");
$arrs = explode(',', $variable);

foreach($arrs as $arr): 
$random_color = $colors[array_rand($colors)];
?>

    <span style="color: <?php echo $random_color; ?>"><?php echo $arr ?></span>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```